# Echo cancellation for mobile development

Tags: android, ios, flutter

When the speaker is active in voice/video calls in mobile apps, the microphone does not pick up the sound coming from the speaker. More precisely, the microphone separates the sounds it detects with methods such as echo cancellation. I could not find a code example to realize this.

Can anyone give me an idea about how I can realize this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box answer to your question but I can provide you with pointers to get the answers.
To start with, I would recommend reading a bit a high-level overview on the [operation of echo cancellation](https://solicall.com/echo-cancellation-art-or-science/): input, output, processing logic etc. Once you understand the basics, you can navigate into the AEC code within the [webRTC](https://webrtc.org/) package.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I read the Android documentation, but the methods there also reduce the sound quality. Webrtc is not implemented in Android.